# Сделать дверь в юнити2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать калитку, открывающуюся на кнопку E, если дистанция от игрока до калитки меньше `1.5`.

При открытии калитки должен поменяться спрайт, и отключиться компонент `BoxCollider2D`. На эту же кнопку калитка должна закрыться: `BoxCollider2D` включиться, а спрайт поменяться обратно.

Вот код двери:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorSetActive : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void OpenDoor()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }

    public void CloseDoor()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

А вот триггер нажатий:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorTriggerButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private DoorSetActive door;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            door.OpenDoor();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            door.CloseDoor();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Код в вопрос нужно вставлять в виде текста, а не картинки

Comment: ща исправлю....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я точно помню, что уже такой вопрос задавался и я сам на него развернуто отвечал. Если получше погуглите, возможно, найдете его.

Главная проблема вашего вопроса в том, что вы не указали, что у вас не работает. Поэтому будем отталкиваться от нуля:

**Используемые функции:**

- [Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode key)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) - обрабатывает нажатие клавиши
- [Vector3.Distance(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) - возвращает расстояние между a и b.

**Возможный код:**

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
publiс class Gate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float OPENABLE_DISTANCE = 1.5f;
    private bool isOpened;
    private SpriteRenderer rend;
    private BoxCollider2D collider;

    [SerializeField] private Sprite OpenedGate, ClosedGate;

    private void Awake () {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }
    private void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.transform.position);
            if (dist <= OPENABLE_DISTANCE) {
                MoveGate(!isOpened);
            }
        }
    }
    private void MoveGate (bool open) {
        if (open) {
            rend.sprite = OpenedGate;
            collider.enabled = false;    
        }
        else {
            rend.sprite = ClosedGate;
            collider.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Где Player - ссылка на игрока

Comment: Скрипт писал от руки, могут быть ошибки/опечатки

Comment: большое спасибо, извиняюсь что сразу не сказал, не работала дистанция

Comment: Ошибка CS0019 Оператор "<=" невозможно применить к операнду типа "Vector3" и "float".

Comment: Поменяй тип переменной dist на float.

Comment: @ТигрСерж Исправил ошибку во второй строке функции Update, как и писал Ярослав. Проверьте теперь. Хотя так как вы приняли ответ, думаю, что у вас все получилось:)